# Angular JS - Manipulating Data in a Service / Factory and Making Sanitized Object Available to Controller

Tags: angularjs

I currently have a simple factory like the following:

```
myFactory.factory('myFactory', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://to/my/api', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET'
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to move some of the data manipulation / sanitation that I am currently doing in my controller to my factory.  I changed my factory to the following:

```
myFactory.factory('myFactory', function($resource){
    var connection = $resource('http://to/my/api', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET'
        }
    });
    var filters = connection.query();
    for(var i = 0; i < filters.data.length; i++){
        // Get the name value in the data array
        var name = filters.data[i].Name;
        // Create new properties in $scope.filters and assign arrays to them.  Each array is a separate filter
        filters[name] = filters.data[i].Values;
    }
    return filters;
});
```

Essentially what I am doing in the above is reordering the structure of the object array returned from the AJAX call.

When I try to console log my 'filters' variable from the factory in my controller, I get an 'undefined' message.  What is wrong with my above factory syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not publicly exposing anything to return `filters`, try:

```
myFactory.factory('myFactory', function($resource){
  return {
     getFilters:function(){
                    var connection = $resource('http://to/my/api', {}, {
                        query: {
                              method: 'GET'
                       }
                    });
          var filters = connection.query();
          for(var i = 0; i < filters.data.length; i++){
          // Get the name value in the data array
          var name = filters.data[i].Name;
          // Create new properties in $scope.filters and assign arrays to them.  Each array is a separate filter
          filters[name] = filters.data[i].Values;
    }
    return filters;
}
}
});
```

and call it like this in your controller:

`$scope.filters = myFactory.getFilters();`

Excuse the horrible formatting, [here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/00AZCVlaxTnoAzWGvS33?p=info).

Comment: Thanks.  As a side question, I noticed that the 'filters' object I get back from connection.query() is a resource object just as it is in my controller.  But unlike in my controller, I can't use 'filters.$promise.then' to resolve it.  How would I handle promises in the factory / service?

Comment: I think resource doesn't need a then, if i'm not mistaken, it's $http that returns a promise. How were you using then with resource in your controller, post a plunk if you can.